# mysql | Conditional left join request

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have a tables:

**votes**

```
record_id   user_id   type

1           1         0
2           1         1
3           1         0
```

**question** // type - 0

```
id   title
1    Title1
2    Title2 
3    Title3
```

**answer** // type-1

```
id   question_id

2    2
```

I need request to get this output data

```
record_id   user_id   type   title

1           1         0      Title1
2           1         1      Title2
3           1         0      Title3
```

I think this will be conditional left join (if type=0 left join with questions table; if type=1 left join with answer table).
How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your logic correctly, this should give the result you're looking for:

```
SELECT
  v.record_id,
  v.user_id,
  v.type,
  COALESCE(q1.title, q2.title) as title
FROM
  votes v LEFT JOIN question q1
  ON v.type=0 AND v.record_id=q1.id
  LEFT JOIN answer a
  ON v.type=1 AND v.record_id=a.id
  LEFT JOIN question q2
  ON a.question_id=q2.question_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  votes.record_id, votes.user_id, votes.type, question.title
FROM
  votes
  LEFT JOIN question ON votes.type=0 AND question.id=votes.record_id
  LEFT JOIN answer ON votes.type=1 AND answer.id=votes.record_id
```

Comment: Could you are more details to this answer?